# If i am choosing the result of predict_proba instead of predict from a SVM classification model, does this mean I am technically using SVM classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm

What actually the `predict_proba()` is? I have read through [Platt's method](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.41.1639&rep=rep1&type=pdf) but I still could not understand the concept of it. Is it another model that run on top SVM classifier's output?

If i am choosing the result from `predict_proba()` instead of `predict()`, am i still consider as using SVM classifier or I am using another model to classify my data?

Comment: Off-topic here, better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @desertnaut, thank you for the suggestion, new to here.

Comment: And you can also contact the sklearn authors on [the mailing list](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/scikit-learn)